# При вызове callback функции с условным типом typescript требует передать параметр с пересечением типов

Tags: typescript, typescript-типы

Есть функция, которая принимает некоторый набор аргументов. В частности callback функцию, которая принимает в аргумент объект или массив объектов, зависящий от другого параметра isArray. Я пытаюсь сделать зависимость.

```
type Option = {
  name: string
  value: string
}

type FunctionProps<IsArray extends boolean | undefined> = {
  isArray?: IsArray
  callback: IsArray extends false
    ? (options: Option) => void
    : (options: option[]) => void
}

const func = <T extends boolean | undefined = false>({isArray, callback}: FunctionProps<T>) => {
  const options: Option[] = /* */
  const currentOption: Option = /* */

  if (isArray) {
    callback(options)  // Argument of type 'Option[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option & Option[]'.
  } else {
    callback(currentOption)  // Argument of type 'Option' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Option & Option[]'.
  }
}
```

При вызове func все работает как нужно, но при вызове callback внутри func typescript хочет получить в качестве аргумента пересечение типов `Option & Option[]`
Можно явно указать тип при вызове `callback(value as Option & Option[])`, но это затрудняет понимание, и не понятно, что в итоге происходит внутри.

```
const single = (option: Option) {
  /* */
}

const multi = (options: Option[]) {
  /* */
}

func({callback: single}) // callback: (options: Option) => void
func({callback: multi, isArray: true})  // callback: (options: Option[]) => void
```

Есть ли возможность внутри более четко определять тип?
P.S. Если я объявлю тип функции вот так, то ничего не поменяется

```
type FunctionProps = {
  isArray: false
  callback: (options: Option) => void
} | {
  isArray: true
  callback: (options: Option[]) => void
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае

```
type FunctionProps<IsArray extends boolean = false>
```

указание в качестве типа `FunctionProps` равносильно `FunctionProps<false>`.

таким образом тут `{isArray, callback}: FunctionProps` типом `isArray` будет только `false`.

---

При применении discriminated union

```
type FunctionProps = {
    isArray: true;
    callback: (oo:Option[])=>void;
}| {
    isArray: false|undefined;
    callback: (o:Option)=>void;
}
```

все начинает работать

[**Playground Link**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)